# AKS custom log log analytics

Tags: solr, azure-log-analytics, azure-aks

I'm not able to collect customs logs inside a pod. I can not find a clear procedure for doing this with log analytics.
For example, I want to collect the Solr logs that are in a pod (/opt/solr/server/logs/solr.log)

I followed this procedure : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-custom-logs but I receive no log.

Do you have some information to share with me ?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with AKS and OMS. it will only collect STDOUT\STDERR from the containers. you need some form of init script that will watch that file and mirror it to the stdout.